# Cannot Delete using Laravel Resource Controller,( This action is unauthorized )

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, resources

I am trying to call delete method using Laravel Resource, however I cannot do that, I keep getting

"*This action is unauthorized error*"

Here are my files

**routes.php**

```
Route::resource('/types','TypeController');
```

**TypeController.php**

```
 public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth');
}

public function destroy(Request $request, Type $type){
    $this->authorize('destroy',$type);
    $type->delete();
    return redirect('/types');
}
```

**TypePolicy.php**

```
class TypePolicy
{

  public function destroy(User $user, Type $type){
     return $user->id === $type->user_id;
  }

}
```

**AuthServiceProvider.php**

```
protected $policies = [
    'App\Model' => 'App\Policies\ModelPolicy',
    'App\Type' => 'App\Policies\TypePolicy',
];
```

**View**

```
{{ Form::open(array('route' => array('types.destroy', $type), 'method' => 'post')) }}
 {{ csrf_field() }}
<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE">
<button type="submit" id="delete-type-{{ $type->id }}" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
{{ Form::close() }}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The route parameter name has to match the parameter name on your method for implicit binding to work. The first argument to `Route::resource` is the resource name, which is used for the route 'parameter' name as well.

Your route parameter is 'types' and your method parameter is 'type'.

If you still want the URL to be 'types' but the param to be 'type', you can tell the router to make your resource route parameters singular.

`RouteServiceProvider@boot`

```
public function boot(Router $router)
{
    $router->singularResourceParameters();

    parent::boot($router);
}
```

Now your URI would be something like `types/{type}` which would match `Type $type` in your method signature.

If you don't want to make all resource route parameters singular, you can do it just for that resource as well.

```
Route::resource('types', 'TypeController', ['parameters' => 'singular']);
```

[Laravel Docs - Controllers - Restful - Naming Resource Route Paramters](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/controllers#restful-naming-resource-route-parameters)